# how to send notification for certificate expiry from Azuredevops pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, ssl, azure-devops

I have a simple azuredevops pipeline to check the ssl certificate expiry of my jfrog instance as below.
But looking for a method to check this weekly and get notification only  when the expiry date is close by 2 months and send a better notification mail regularly for each weeks.

```
  - job: ssl_cert
    workspace:
      clean: all
    pool: 
     name: linux-spoke
    steps:            
    - script: |
        curl https://myjfrog instance -vk 2>&1 | grep expire
      displayName: 'check certificate'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can send an email notification if your certificate's expiry date is less than 60 days. For that, you can do the following:-

- Check if the expiry date is less than 60 days
- If yes, use `exit 1` to purposefully fail the script task
- Get notified only if the pipeline fails using [notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops)

You can [configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). The time zone for cron schedules is UTC

The sample `yaml` pipeline below is configured as follows

- To run on all Wednesdays at 17:00 UTC
- Evaluates if `expiry_days` is less than 60 days
- If the evaluation is successful, the build will succeed.
- If the evaluation is unsuccessful, the build will fail and the error will be logged to the pipeline. For more details on logging commands, check [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#task-commands)

```
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: 00 17 * * Wed
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

pool:
  name: default

workspace:
  clean: all
steps:

- script: |
    #!/bin/bash
    expiry_days=$(( ($(date -d "$(openssl x509 -in myjfrog.crt  -enddate -noout | cut -d= -f2)" '+%s') - $(date '+%s')) / 86400 )) #you can have your own logic here
    if [[ $expiry_days -lt 60 ]]
    then
      echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Certificate expires in $expiry_days days"
      exit 1
    fi
  displayName: 'check certificate'
```

I have created a personal notification subscription which will send an email only if the above pipeline fails with the below config. But you can create personal, project, etc

- Category: build -> Template: a build fails
- Deliver to: Other email -> your email address
- Filter -> A specific team project -> Sandbox (your project name)
- Filter criteria -> Field -> Definition name: cert (your pipeline's name) & Status: Failed

[image]

If the above pipeline is scheduled for a run, you will receive an email to the configured email address (only if it fails). Notice that the logged error (which is the remaining days) is also sent to the email. This is because the pipeline has logged this using the logging commands.

[image]

Comment: Great.. But here I dont have certificate  localy or cant sore anywhere. So looking for someway to directly get it from the web url itself, for example- curl https://myjfrog instance -vk 2>&1 | grep expire , and planning to add many other apps also in similar way. here am stuck by finding the  above commands

Comment: xpiry_days=$(( ($(date -d "$(openssl x509 -in myjfrog.crt  -enddate -noout | cut -d= -f2)" '+%s') - $(date '+%s')) / 86400 )) #you can have your own logic here
    if [[ $expiry_days -lt 60 ]]
    then
      echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Certificate expires in $expiry_days days"
      exit 1
    fi

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it helps - but heres a gist to hook all of this into a github action instead of Azure, and notify slack of the results every monday at 2pm :)

https://gist.github.com/benkitzelman/56103dfba3e10429438034f6a5759b26